# Recursion in xsd

Tags: xml, recursion, xsd

How can I make recursion in xsd schema using predefined complexType as below:

```
  <xs:complexType name="style">
      <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
      <xs:attribute name="color" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
  </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="children">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="div" type="style">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element ref="children" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
```

Comment: Please post sample XML which you would like to be valid according to your XSD.

Comment: `<div>
      <div/>
      <text/>
      <line/>
      <image/>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th/>
          <th/>
          <th/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td/>
          <td/>
          <td/>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <polygon/>
      <circle/>
      <rectangle/>
      <barcode/>
    </div>`
And bare in mind, that every element can have tree like that, not only div.

Comment: Also, every element should have attributes like `<div background-image="dot.jpg" background-position="center center" background-size="14 14" height="16" width="16" margin-right="4 />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like the following XML to be valid,

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<children xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="try.xsd">
  <div name="John" color="red">
    <children>
      <div name="Mary" color="white"/>
      <div name="Fred" color="blue"/>
    </children>
  </div>
</children>
```

then this recursive XSD will fit the bill:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> 
  <xs:element name="children">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="div" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element ref="children" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
            <xs:attribute name="color" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: It would work, but the thing is, I have A LOT attributes in style, and A LOT of elements (not only div). This is just example, but I need whole mechanism. I will provide better scope tommorow from work.

Comment: Many attributes and elements do not fundamentally change the recursion.  Sure, when you get a chance, show a representative sample of the XML you wish to cover, and it'll be no problem to update the solution to fit your needs.

Comment: When you look at my example XML, schema gonna look pretty nasty, but I ended up using this approach.